# Gradle on Linux: Execution failed for task ':compileJava'. > java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException

Tags: java, gradle

I know there are plenty of other questions similar to this, but none of them are the exact same as my issue, and I've thus not found a solution to my issue, despite looking for it.

I'm trying to build a YouTube-uploader to practice my Java, and as per [YouTube's instructions](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/java), I'm using Gradle to do it. I've set up the Quickstart file and the build.gradle file, but trying to run it, Gradle throws an error:

```
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
```

Running with the `--info` flag tells me

```
> Task :compileJava FAILED
Task ':compileJava' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has failed previously.
All input files are considered out-of-date for incremental task ':compileJava'.
Compiling with JDK Java compiler API.
```

The full build scan with more detailed information can be found [here](https://scans.gradle.com/s/l7zgsk4fs7f42/).

I'm running the following:

```
$ java -version
    openjdk version "9-internal"
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)

$ gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.6
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-02-28 13:36:36 UTC
Revision:     8fa6ce7945b640e6168488e4417f9bb96e4ab46c

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9 compiled on February 2 2017
JVM:          9-internal (Oracle Corporation 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OS:           Linux 4.13.0-36-generic amd64
```

I'm at a complete loss here. I've reinstalled OpenJDK and Gradle, to no avail. How do I resolve this error?

Comment: I think there is some issue in java versions. Could you please try java 8 version and then with java 9

Comment: The outcome specified in the question is for Java 9. Trying Java 8 didn't cause any different result.

Comment: is the project is available in github?

Comment: I don't have it up on github no, but the build file and quickstart file code is copied from the [youtube guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/java), and the [build scan](https://scans.gradle.com/s/l7zgsk4fs7f42/) provides additional information as well.

Comment: @Tijmen I'm also facing the same problem. Did you get any solution?

Comment: @Razib Yes, I did, but I forgot what exactly it was. I believe I had to change the tolerance or something similar in my IDE (Eclipse).